# How to get the elements inside of the anchor tag?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

Pardon me i am very new to web scraping in Selenium and python. I am trying to scrape the contents of supermarket website which has the following part in html

```
<div class="itemDescription">
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="INR">
            <meta itemprop="price" content="23.00">
        <h4 class=""><strong class="price js-effective-mrp" data-currency="₹">₹ 23.00 </strong>
                                    <s class="js-actual-mrp" style="display:none;"></s>
                                <br><a href="/fresh-onion-red-v-1-kg-p.php" class="">Fresh Onion Red <span class="item-quantity">1 Kg</span></a></h4>
                    </div>
```

I needed the prices, quantity and name of the product.

Below is the code that i have written but it doesnt parse the elements correctly.

```
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('itemDescription')
sname =div.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
squantity =driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item-quantity')
sprice = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "js-effective-mrp", " " ))]')
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xPath fro price:

```
//strong[@class='price js-effective-mrp' and @data-currency='₹']
```

or if you want all currencies:

```
//strong[@class='price js-effective-mrp']
```

This for link:

```
//div[@class='itemDescription']//a
```

And this for quantity:

```
//span[@class = 'item-quantity']
```

Example:

```
sname = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='itemDescription']//a")
squantity = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'item-quantity']")
sprice = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[@class='price js-effective-mrp' and @data-currency='₹']")

print(squantity.text) # prints quantity
print(sname.text) # prints name
print(sprice.text) # prints price
```

According your feedback, you cannot get text from a list, but you can get a text from every element in the list like this:

```
sname_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='itemDescription']//a")
for sname in sname_list:
    print(sname.text) # print the text of every element in the list
```

Comment: Hallo Andrei,Thanks for the quick response .i dont know i f i sound stupid but is this the correct way to parse that since i am getting an invalid syntax error.
sname = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//a[@href = '/fresh-onion-red-v-1-kg-p.php'])

squantity =driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//span[@class = 'item-quantity'])

Comment: I have added infor in the answer, please have a look

Comment: I am getting a blank for the link one
//a[@href = '/fresh-onion-red-v-1-kg-p.php']
Also is there any other way to get the description (sname)(in this case -Fresh Onion Red )in a dynamic way because i need it for all the elements in the web page.

Comment: I have changed xPath to the link, please try it

Comment: Thank you, Andrei all the above worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Happy to hear it! If you are satisfied with my help, please mark my answer by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button

Comment: Just one more help i am trying to iterate it for all the elements in the website
sname = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='itemDescription']//a")
by driver.find_elements and using a for loop i am getting 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I have added an explanation and example, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this logic, Xcuse with syntex,

```
String strProductDescription = driver.find_element_by_class_name('itemDescription').getText();
String arrString = strProductDescription.split("SomeDelimeter");
```

Answer (score 0):

for **MRP** you can try this :

```
sprice = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('strong.price.js-effective-mrp')
```

then you can extract the text using .text method :

```
print(sprice.text)
```

for quantity

```
squantity = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.item-quantity')
print(squantity.text)
```

for name :

```
sname = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='itemDescription']//a")
print(sname.text)
```

Note that with this xpath : `//div[@class='itemDescription']//a`  you will get this `Fresh Onion Red 1 Kg` as output.

Basically **Fresh Onion Red** is a text node.

Comment: Thank you so much @cruisepandey the price thing worked. :)
can you help me with the quantity and description?. Also just wanted to tell you that this is going to be a selenium automated process for all the elements on the page.

Comment: is there a way i can iterate it for all the elements on the web page.? i tried but i am getting error